# GetType возвращает null

Tags: c#

Всем добра!
Почему `Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.TreeView")` 
Возвращает null?

Comment: MSDN говорит, что надо указывать сборку: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Потому что не указана сборка, где искать тип, и тип не находится в текущей вызывающей сборке или `mscorlib`.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, читал. Собственно, там  решения не нашел. Типа такого вы имели в виду: `Type.GetType(@"System.Windows.Forms.TreeView, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")`? Если да, то не то ( строку получил через Assembly.FullName) - все равно null. И если надо указывать сборку, то почему тогда `Type.GetType("System.Int32")` и `Type.GetType("System.Object")` работают без проблем?

Comment: @PetSerAl, а как узнать точное имя сборки?

Comment: О, нашел! Спасибо) `System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`

Comment: Отлично, напишите ответ, если получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос так:

```
Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.TreeView, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
```

Оказывается сборка System.Windows.Forms не включена в mscorlib. Всем спасибо